# Is there a way to create 2-color and 3-color scale conditional formats in PHPExcel?

Tags: phpexcel

I'm trying to apply 2-color scale and 3-color scale conditional formats to an Excel sheet that I am creating with PHPExcel.  Looking at the documentation, it appears that PHPExcel doesn't support these types of formats (only the "Classic" ones).

Short of waiting for an enhancement to PHPExcel, does anyone know of any way I could implement these sorts of gradient formats?  I don't suppose there is any sort of API for adding "raw" Excel XML, or anything to that effect?

Or maybe other ideas?

Thanks!